# composite polynomials error

Tags: java

I have a question to complete using Java Polynomials. I've set up all my code and it looks to be ok but with my composite method I receive a different output than is expected.

```
class Polyonmial
{ 
    final static private int mantissa=52;
    final static private double epsilon=Math.pow(2.0,-mantissa);
    private double coefficient=0.0;
    private int power=0;
    private Polynomial successor=null;
    public Polynomial(double coefficient, int power)
    { 
        if (Double.isNaN(coefficient)) return;
        if (Math.abs(coefficient)<epsilon) return;
        if (power<0) return;
        this.coefficient=coefficient;
        this.power=power;
    }

final public double coefficient(int power)
{ 
    if (power<0) return 0.0;
    Polynomial traverser=this;
    do
    { 
        if (traverser.power<power) return 0.0;
        if (traverser.power==power) return traverser.coefficient;
        traverser=traverser.successor;
    }
    while (traverser!=null);
    return 0.0;
}

final public Polynomial composite(Polynomial that)
{
     if (that==null) return null;
     Polynomial thisClone = this.clone();
     Polynomial thatClone = that.clone();
     Polynomial temp = new Polynomial(0.0,0);
     Polynomial result = new Polynomial(0.0,0);

     while(thisClone != null)
     {
         if (thisClone.power == 0) 
         {
             temp.coefficient = 1.0;
             temp.power = 0;
         }
         else
         {
             if (thisClone.power == 1) 
             temp = thatClone;
         }
         //System.out.println("temp:"+temp);

         while(temp != null)
         {
            temp.coefficient = thisClone.coefficient*temp.coefficient;
            result = result.plus(temp);
            temp = temp.successor;
         }
         temp = new Polynomial(0.0,0);
         thisClone=thisClone.successor;
     }
     return result;
}

final public Polynomial[] dividedBy(Polynomial that) 
{ 
    if (that==null) return null;
    if (that.coefficient==0.0) return null;
    Polynomial quotient=new Polynomial(0.0,0);
    Polynomial remainder=this.clone();

    Polynomial traverser = this.clone();
    Polynomial resultoftemp = new Polynomial(0.0, 0);
    Polynomial temp = new Polynomial(0.0, 0);

    double thiscoffe = this.coefficient(this.degree());
    double thatcoffe = that.coefficient(that.degree());

    if(that.coefficient !=0 && that.power !=0)
    {
        quotient.coefficient = thatcoffe / thiscoffe;
        quotient.power = that.power - this.power; 
    }

    while(traverser !=null)
    {
        temp.power = quotient.power + traverser.power;
        temp.coefficient = quotient.coefficient * traverser.coefficient;
        traverser=traverser.successor;

        resultoftemp = resultoftemp.plus(temp);

        remainder = that.minus(resultoftemp);
    }

    Polynomial[] result=new Polynomial[2];
    result[0]=quotient;
    result[1]=remainder;
    return result;
}

final public Polynomial integrate()
{ 
    if (this.coefficient==0.0) return new Polynomial(0.0,0);
    Polynomial result=this.clone();

    Polynomial temp = new Polynomial(0.0, 0);
    Polynomial rstemp = new Polynomial(0.0, 0);

    while(result!=null)
    {
        rstemp.power = result.power + 1;
        rstemp.coefficient = result.coefficient / (result.power +1);
        result = result.successor;
        temp = temp.plus(rstemp);
    }
    return result;
}

final public Polynomial minus(Polynomial that)
{ 
    if (that==null) return null;
    if (this.equals(that)) return new Polynomial(0.0,0);
    Polynomial result=this.clone();
    if (that.coefficient==0.0) return result;
    Polynomial traverser=that;
    do
    { 
        add(result,-traverser.coefficient,traverser.power);
        traverser=traverser.successor;
    }
    while (traverser!=null);
    return result;
}

final public int powerMax()
{ 
    int max=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    Polynomial traverser=this;
    do
    {
        if (max<traverser.power) max=traverser.power;
        traverser=traverser.successor;
    }
    while (traverser!=null);
    return max;
}

final public int powerMin()
{ 
    int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Polynomial traverser=this;
    do
    {
        if (min>traverser.power) min=traverser.power;
        traverser=traverser.successor;
    }
    while (traverser!=null);
    return min;
}

}
```

In my expected output file I am supposed to receive this:

```
(-1.0*X^1+1.0).composite(-1.0*X^1+1.0)=
1.0*X^1
```

But instead I receive:

```
(-1.0*X^1+1.0).composite(-1.0*X^1+1.0)=
1.0*X^1+1.0
```

Any tips or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running your first example ((-1.0*X^1+1.0).composite(-1.0*X^1+1.0)) through a debugger? That example seems rather straightforward, and worth stepping through. It seems rather peculiar the -1.0+1.0 isn't happening.

Comment: @ccoakley I assume its a problem with the composite method

Comment: @Bill: Good, that's where I first looked, and I found a single apparent bug. If I have misinterpreted something, please let me know.

Comment: @Bill Please don't wipe out your question when you find an answer. That's not how this site works.

Comment: lol, "fixed (please delete)"? Did you understand that one of the points of a Q+A site is that most of the time, your question was already raised by someone else, so you can search it in the database? Questions and answers belong to the community, you should not remove it if you have solved YOUR problem.

Comment: This is not how stackoverflow works. If everyone deleted their question once answered it would be a useless resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have slightly changed your composite method as so (logically equivalent, brace moves and println additions):

```
final public Polynomial composite(Polynomial that) {
    if (that==null) return null;
    Polynomial thisClone = this.clone();
    Polynomial thatClone = that.clone();
    Polynomial temp = new Polynomial(0.0,0);
    Polynomial result = new Polynomial(0.0,0);

    while(thisClone != null) {
        System.out.println("composite with term degree: " + thisClone.power);
        if (thisClone.power == 0) {
            temp.coefficient = 1.0;
            temp.power = 0;
        } else if (thisClone.power == 1) {
            temp = thatClone;
        } else {
            for(int i=2; i<=thisClone.power; i++) {
                temp = temp.plus(thatClone.times(thatClone));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("temp heading in: " + temp);

        while(temp != null) {
            temp.coefficient = thisClone.coefficient*temp.coefficient;
            result = result.plus(temp);
            temp = temp.successor;
        }
        System.out.println("result so far: " + result);
        temp = new Polynomial(0.0,0);
        thisClone=thisClone.successor;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and for the example `(-1.0*X^1+1.0).composite(-1.0*X^1+1.0)`, this is the output:

> composite with term degree: 1
>   temp heading in: -1.0*X^1+1.0
>   result so far: 1.0*X^1
>   composite with term degree: 0
>   temp heading in: 1.0
>   result so far: 1.0*X^1+1.0

Am I correct to believe that the first "result so far" should be "-1.0*X^1-1.0"?

If so, let's examine the loop:

```
        while(temp != null) {
            temp.coefficient = thisClone.coefficient*temp.coefficient;
            result = result.plus(temp);
            temp = temp.successor;
        }
```

I think this is your problem: `result = result.plus(temp)` is adding not just the "current term" to temp, but also the successor term. But then you loop on temp by setting it equal to its successor and do it again!

I think the solution is something like this (first calculate all temp terms, then update result):

```
    Polynomial looptemp = temp;
    while(looptemp != null) {
        looptemp.coefficient = thisClone.coefficient*looptemp.coefficient;
        looptemp = looptemp.successor;
    }
    result = result.plus(temp);
```

At the very least, it works for the single example I tried.

Comment: @Bill: Does it fail for any example of degree less than 2? I also thought your `temp = temp.plus(thatClone.times(thatClone));` looked a little suspicious, but I didn't try an example that exercised that code. Unfortunately, it is my bedtime. Good luck!

Comment: @Bill: Just a debugging suggestion: Simplify your test case even further. Try things with only two terms (to exercise successor) and one term (in case there's no successor problem). There's no compelling reason (yet) to test with three terms. I expect that if an error exists, it can be exercised with two terms, and hopefully NOT with only one. The negative coefficients are good, but make them different (ignoring sign, you have 3 1.0 coefficients in your test case). Comment again and I'll check when I get home from work. Again, good luck!